# Maatwebsite Excel 3.1 : how do I skip duplicate data when imported?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I made import data using Excel on Laravel Maatwebsite Excel 3.1. but when in the database there is the same data (Primary Key) then there is an error message

> integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '188281' for key
>   'PRIMARY'

I have tried to understand the documentation of the Maatwebsite but it still fails

```
public function storeData(Request $request)
        {
            //VALIDASI
            $this->validate($request, [
                'file' => 'required|mimes:xls,xlsx'
            ]);
        if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
            $file = $request->file('file');

            // dd($file); //GET FILE;
            Excel::import(new MahasiswaImport, $file); //IMPORT FILE
            return redirect('/mahasiswa')->with(['status' => 'Upload success']);
        }
        return redirect('/mahasiswa')->with(['error' => 'Please choose file before']);
    }



<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Mahasiswa;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;

class MahasiswaImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithChunkReading, ShouldQueue

{

  use Importable;
/**
* @param array $row
*
* @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
*/
public function model(array $row)
{
    return new Mahasiswa([
      'nim' => $row['nim'],
      'slug' => str_slug($row['nim']),
      'nama_mahasiswa' => $row['nama_mahasiswa'],
      'email' => $row['email'],
      'kode_kelas' => $row['kode_kelas'],
      'alamat' => $row['alamat'],
      'kode_jurusan' => $row['kode_jurusan'],
      'kode_tahun_akademik' => $row['kode_tahun_akademik'],
      'no_hp' => $row['no_hp'],
      'tempat_lahir' => $row['tempat_lahir'],
      // 'tanggal_lahir' => $row['tanggal_lahir'],
      'password' => $row['password']


    ]);
}


public function chunkSize(): int
{
    return 1000;
}

}
```

[image: dd($row) in model]

Comment: Can you `dd($row)` in your model function and provide it?

Comment: Oke. I have entered into the post

Comment: Did you try something like this: `$data = Mahasiswa::create([
      'nim' => $row['nim'],
      'slug' => str_slug($row['nim']),
      'nama_mahasiswa' => $row['nama_mahasiswa'],
      'email' => $row['email'],
      'kode_kelas' => $row['kode_kelas'],
      'alamat' => $row['alamat'],
      'kode_jurusan' => $row['kode_jurusan'],
      'kode_tahun_akademik' => $row['kode_tahun_akademik'],
      'no_hp' => $row['no_hp'],
      'tempat_lahir' => $row['tempat_lahir'],
      'password' => $row['password']
]); return $data;`

Comment: Your error is from sql because you have duplicated key for your primary key. Are some data from `$row` your primary key?

Comment: Yes. NIM is Primary key,. therefore if the data is already in the database, then the data is skipped

Comment: So you need some kind of validation in your import?

Comment: Yes, i need validation. sorry if the statement is post ambiguous

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to validate your `row`. You can read docs about [Row Validation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html).

So you need something like this in your Import:

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'nim' => Rule::unique('mahasiswa', 'nim'), // Table name, field in your db
    ];
}

public function customValidationMessages()
{
    return [
        'nim.unique' => 'Custom message',
    ];
}
```

Or some deprecated way:

```
public function model(array $data)
{
    
       $data = Mahasiswa::find($row['nim']);
       if (empty($data)) {
          return new Mahasiswa([
                 'nim' => $row['nim'],
                 'slug' => str_slug($row['nim']),
                 ...
                 ]);
       } 
   
}
```

Comment: sorry, but an error appears "Class 'App\Imports\Rule' not found" why?

Comment: Add `use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;` in your Import, and let me know whats happening.

Comment: it can, but the data is not inserted into the database. for example, I enter 2 data into excel, 1 data is in the database and 1 data does not yet exist. Can the existing data in Excel be skipped and the existing data stored?

Comment: Try with second way, I updated my answer. That should work.

Comment: You are welcome. Maybe you can try to find better way but I think it's helpful. Good luck!

Comment: It showing following error:

#message: "Trying to access array offset on value of type int"

Answer (score 0):

Using Maatwebsite Excel 3.1; how do I skip duplicate data when imported? You can check if any column already has the value in the db like this.

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    $bin = DB::table('bin_info')->get();

    // Get all bin number from the $bin collection
    $bin_number = $bin->pluck('bin_number');
    
    // Checking if the bin number is already in the database
    if ($bin_number->contains($row[0]) == false) 
    {
        return new Bin([
            'bin_number' => $this->binNumberCheck($row[0]),
            'type' => $this->typeCheck($row[1]),
            'product' => $row[2],
            'category' => $row[3],
            'bank' => $row[4],
        ]);
    }
    else null; // if the bin number is already in the database, return null
}
```